# why read action in open graph not submit

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

i have created a app, an object(article) an action(read), and I want to test to publish but i submit alway alert 'Error occured'. why?

head code

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/article#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxx" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="object_url" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Tachnomo" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Drive car" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readnews()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/news.reads?article=object_url',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Drive was successfully published with ID : ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: What error? Give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

"object_url" is supposed to be an encoded URL, not the words "object_url".